# model attribute conditionally required - how?

Tags: php, validation, yii, yii2

I have a model `User`, that has the attributes `type` and `payment_id`.

`payment_id` is required when `type == 1` **or**  `type == 3`, but may be empty if `type == 2`

In my form, `type` is a dropdown containing the values `1` `2` and `3`. `payment_id` is a regular text field. When value 2 is chosen, I am still prompted to enter the `payment_id`.

Code that I have tried according to the [yii2 docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$when-detail):

```
class User
{    
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['payment_id', 'type'], 'integer'],
            [
                ['payment_id'], 'required', 'when'=>function ($model) {
                    return ($model->type == 1 || $model->type == 3);
                }
            ],
            ...
        ];
    }
    ...
}
```

But even if `type == 2` (in the dropdown), I am still getting the error `Payment ID may not be empty`.

Can anybody point out my mistake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution, here's the working code:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [
            ['payment_id'], 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
                return ($model->type == 1 || $model->type == 3);
            }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
                return ($('#user-type').value == 1 || $('#user-type').value == 3);
            }"
        ],
    ];
}
```

**Explanation:** my form was being validated on the client side first, preventing me from posting the form. So I needed to add the same condition to the client side validation using `whenClient`.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
return ($model->type == 1 || $model->type == 3);
```

To:

```
return ($model->$type !== 2 ? ($model->type == 1 || $model->type == 3) : $model->type == NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to work; I am still getting the error `Payment ID may not be empty`